# CCSprite scale - How can I change method of scaling?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, kobold2d

I want to scale CCSprite by nearest neighbor method.
But just setting sprite.scale causes blurred scaling ( I think it's bilinear or something)

So how can I change the method of scaling?
Is that possible?

Comment: all the drawing is in the CCSprite's draw method. if you want, you can try to play around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[sprite.texture setAliasTexParameters];
```

Keep in mind that this will affect all the sprites that are using the texture.